# Using wildcard instead of specific values while setting automatic download option

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I want to download automatically any type of file without any prompt window appearing. Is this possible without declaring the type explicitly in the setPreference method??

Example:

Instead of:

```
fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "applicati‌​on/pdf,application/x‌​-pdf,application/oct‌​et-stream");
```

Is there any way like this:

```
fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "*");
```

Comment: Just wondering: whats the purpose here? Just to make testing easier?

Comment: @GhostCat yes, i've to download files from various categories/types. If I do that hard-code  it may cause issues. Cause, I am not told the types to download yet. So, I am searching for wildcard like option.

Comment: @Andersson did you see my question well??? Definitely, it's not a duplicate. I know how to search for duplicate.

Comment: @optimist_creeper, the point of question is "how to set `Firefox Profile` to download any type of files?" in both tickets. And there is an answer for your question- "There is no way to do so except to list required MIME types"